# Add an ImageLayer which is not antialias'ed, but remains pixelated on zoom

Tags: cesiumjs

Is there a way to add a `Cesium.SingleTileImageryProvider` image to a Cesium map which will behave like an image set to `image-rendering: pixelated`, like [in this example](https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/image-rendering-pixelated/)?

I have an image overlay which I'd prefer to remain pixelated when zoomed in.